# InvalidDimensions Error. How can I gain access to the Dataset to format it before the tablib error through django-import-export

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-import-export, import-csv

I'm using `django-import-export`and receiving the following error when trying to upload a csv file:

```
InvalidDimensions encountered while trying to read file
```

I know that this is a `tablib` error, and due to the fact that I have an empty line between each row in my csv, as well as blank lines at the end of file. I want to gain access to the dataset before the import to format it properly. I've tried overriding the `import_obj`, `before_import` and `before_import_row` methods, but that doesn't seem to work. None of the other methods seems to work either.

> admin.py

```
    class UpdateResource(resources.ModelResource):
        def before_import_row(self, row, **kwargs):
            print(row)
```

I've just been trying to find the correct method to use before the error. I've had no luck gaining access to the `tablib.Dataset` resource yet. Any help would be great.